# json_normalize: Accessing data that is both in library and array form

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to extract the values for the 'Resource' in the following nested json

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "A-----------",
            "Action": [
                "logs:C-----------",
                "logs:P-----------"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "a----",
                "b----",
                "c----"
            ]
        }
        {
            "Effect": "A-----------",
            "Action": "l-----------p",
            "Resource": "a-----------*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "A-----------",
            "Action": [
                "-----------",
                "l-----------"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "a----",
                "b----"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the the 'Resource' information is in an array `"Resource":["value"]` for the first and third example, however the second one is in library form `{"Resource": "value"}`

**In the actual json file I'm extracting the information from, most of the 'Resource' data is in array form.**

I can get the information for the array with the following code:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(response['Document']['Statement'], record_path=['Resource'])
```

but since the 'Resource' in library form is between the two in array form, it gives me this error:

`TypeError(TypeError: {'Resource': '----'} has non list value ---- for path Resource. Must be list or null.`

I know I can access the library information with the code below but I want to get the information for all of the 'Resource' instances in one go.

```
table_df = pd.json_normalize(response['Statement'])
table_df = table_df.reindex(columns=['Resource'])
```

What approach could I solve this with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pandas to manipulate a json.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "A-----------",
            "Action": [
                "logs:C-----------",
                "logs:P-----------"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "a----",
                "b----",
                "c----"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "A-----------",
            "Action": "l-----------p",
            "Resource": "a-----------*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "A-----------",
            "Action": [
                "-----------",
                "l-----------"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "a----",
                "b----"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

resource = list()
for statement in data['Statement']:
    if isinstance(statement['Resource'], list):
        resource.extend(statement['Resource'])
    else:
        resource.append(statement['Resource'])
df = pd.Series(resource)
```

you then get a series that looks like:

```
df
0            a----
1            b----
2            c----
3    a-----------*
4            a----
5            b----
dtype: object
```

Comment: A simple but very effective solution. Thank you!

Comment: I found a new problem when using this solution. Please look at the edit in the main post.

Comment: I'll try to split the list on ',' but I'm leaving the post open for now in case there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you :)

Comment: I ran into another small issue, if you don't mind please also give me an opinion on the following: The code iterates successfully until it gets to `"Resource": "*"`. When the * is an array `"Resource": ["*"]` it parses it successfully. The error I'm getting is `TypeError: string indices must be integers` on the line `if isinstance(statement['Resource'], list):`.

Comment: @ire this error is telling you that `statement` is not a dictionary. so basically it is no following your current json structure. its like you have `[{}, {}, {}, '*']`

Comment: I understand. Thank you